# Laravel 4 Simple form validation

Tags: php, forms, validation, laravel-4, laravel-blade

I have a validator that always passes.I need it to fail if username has less than 3 characters.

Here are my routes:

```
Route::get('/', function()
{
return View::make('validation.form');
 });

 Route::post('registration', function()
{
// Fetch all request data.
 $data = Input::all();
 var_dump($data);
// Build the validation constraint set.
 $rules = array(
 'username' => 'alpha_num|min:3' //or username =>array('alpha_num','min:3')
 );
var_dump($rules);
// Create a new validator instance.
$validator = Validator::make($data, $rules);

if ($validator->passes()) {
// Normally we would do something with the data.
return 'Data was saved.';
}


return 'data not saved';

});
```

And bellow is 'my' form

```
{{ Form::open(array('url' => 'registration')) }}

{{-- Username field. ------------------------}}
{{ Form::label('username', 'Username') }}
{{ Form::text('username') }}
<br/>

{{-- Email address field. -------------------}}
{{ Form::label('email', 'Email address') }}
{{ Form::email('email') }}
<br/>


{{-- Password field. ------------------------}}
{{ Form::label('password', 'Password') }}
{{ Form::password('password') }}
<br/>


{{-- Password confirmation field. -----------}}
{{ Form::label('password_confirmation', 'Password confirmation') }}
 {{ Form::password('password_confirmation') }}
<br/>


{{-- Form submit button. --------------------}}
{{ Form::submit('Register') }}


{{ Form::close() }}
```

When I click the submit button I am always routed to /registration with the message data saved.Why does the validator not working..?Any idea

Comment: Can you add the var_dumps?

Comment: The data is successfully passed..i used required also and it failed with empty input..but shouldn t min:3 make it fail.?

Answer (score 1):

Require rule checks whether the input is filled or not..so if you give an empty input without require rule the validator ignores min:3 and it successes..but if you give two chars as input it will fail.so in order to avoid empty data use require rule..

Comment: I think you nailed it

Answer (score 0):

```
'username' =>  = 'required|alpha_num|min:3|max:15';
```

Comment: pls add a explanation for your solution - http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer